# Recursive function to create triangle

Tags: python, function, recursion, fibonacci, triangle

what is wrong with my code to generate the folowing output. I need to use recursive function to complete the program but I get the wrong output.

```
def computeTriangle(levels):
`
    if levels == 0:
        return []
    elif levels == 1:
        return [[1]]
    elif levels == 2:
        return [[1], [1, 1]]
    else:
        triangle = computeTriangle(levels - 1)
        prev_row = triangle[-1]
        row = [1]
        for i in range(1, levels - 1):
            row.append(prev_row[i - 1] + prev_row[i])
        row.append(1)
        triangle.append(row)
        return triangle


def printTriangle(triangle, levels):
    if levels == 0:
        return`your text`
    printTriangle(triangle, levels - 1)
    for j in range(levels):
        print(triangle[levels - 1][j], end=' ')
    print()


def main():
    levels = 5
    triangle = computeTriangle(levels)
    printTriangle(triangle, levels)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I expect to get this output:
1

1  1

2  1  2

3  2   2  3

5  3  4  3  5

but I get this output:
1
1 1
1 2 1
1 3 3 1
1 4 6 4 1

Answer (score 0):

i guess this is pascal triangle,
you can try this :

```
def pascals_array(numRow):
        if numRows == 1:
            return [[1]]
        result = pascals_array(numRows-1)
        return result + [[1] + [result[-1][i-1] + result[-1][i] for i in range(1,numRows-1)] + [1]]
```

or you can use this :

```
# input n
n = 5
 
for i in range(1, n+1):
    for j in range(0, n-i+1):
        print(' ', end='')
 
    # first element is always 1
    C = 1
    for j in range(1, i+1):
 
        # first value in a line is always 1
        print(' ', C, sep='', end='')
 
        # using Binomial Coefficient
        C = C * (i - j) // j
    print()
```